# Angular 2 show/hide components/parts based on roles/claims

Tags: angular

I am trying to understand best practices about security aspect of angular application.
Lets say i have a view with details screen of the model. What i want to be able to do, based on roles/permissions for the given user (gotten from jwt claims, for example) is:

1. enable/disable certain input fields based on the fact if user is/isn't of certain role so, effectively some roles can edit the record and some can't
2. show/hide 'save' button again based on role, again to prevent certain roles from editing

i understand there is canActivate but if feels like on a component level and what i need is a bit more granular approach to change things within components based on roles.

what are the best practices?

Comment: Just use `*ngIf="..."`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume you have a profile saved somewhere in an object.

```
{
  name: 'asdas',
  role: 1 // for example, 1 for normal user, 2 for admin
}
```

1. enable/disable certain input fields based on the fact if user is/isn't of certain role so, effectively some roles can edit the record and some can't

you can add disabled based on his role

```
[disabled]="user.role === 1"
```

2. show/hide 'save' button again based on role, again to prevent certain roles from editing

Same for this one

```
*ngIf="user.role === 2"
```

However, you want to double check these things in the backend if the user is actually an admin when editing fields f.e.

Comment: thank you for your answer. yes, of course, server side check is in place. for the moment i am looking only at front end behavior.

Comment: What if I have 20 compoments 7 diferent roles and I have various scenarious for each role (the compoments they can see), writing ngIf's sounds like and awful idea to me, any hints how to handle that

Comment: I need to implement the same thing. So I think that I will create a guard, an Observable service, and/or a directive to check if the connected user has the required permission to access the component/element. So that I would be able to:

Comment: I need to implement the same thing. So I think that I will create a guard, an Observable service, and/or a directive to check if the connected user has the required permission to access the component/element.

So that I would be able to:

1. using guard: prevent a user to access a specific route if not allowed

2. using service: set some component properties used in the template to conditionnally display elements. Such as: `<button *ngIf="canEdit$ | async"></button>`

3. directly use the permission in the template: for instance: `<div [app-permission]="'canUpdateUser'"></div>`

Comment: can u give more details on 3rd option how to implement that.

Comment: If this config becomes to complex its maybe better to build a customComponent for each a NG Guard? isnt it?

Answer (score 7):

Use [Ng2Permission](https://github.com/JavadRasouli/ng2-permission) module [directives](https://github.com/JavadRasouli/ng2-permission/blob/master/doc/managing-permissions.md) for show/hide or enable/disable element.

For example assume you already with `PermissionService` defined some permission among `Admin`, `Reporte` and etc. Now below example, `delete button` enabled when `Admin` permission defined or added to permission store. See this link: [PermissionService](https://github.com/JavadRasouli/ng2-permission/blob/master/doc/managing-permissions.md)

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" 
  [hasPermission]="['Admin']"
  onAuthorizedPermission="enable"
  onUnauthorizedPermission="disable">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  Delete
</button>
```