# How can i display an angular component(including html) in two different ways(styles)

Tags: angular

I have a requirement to develop a a form in two different ways. When the user is not logged in, I have to simply display it as an informational form (which is a simple html) and when the user is logged in, I have to show another type of form with some fields and validations for the user to complete before they hit an action button. How can I achieve this? Any suggestions or a sample code will be of great help. Thanks

Comment: Your question is too broad. It is possible but you have to do it yourself first. This might be a good starting point: [1](https://blog.strongbrew.io/display-a-component-based-on-role/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848789/angular-2-show-hide-components-parts-based-on-roles-claims)

Answer (score 0):

Your example is too vague to be dealt with.

You could implement a user service to keep the logged in status of your user and then provide it to your form component to get this boolean. Then, simple `*ngIf` could be used to display the needed form controls.